# Show that the function $\max\left(x^2, |x|\right)$ is convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

We define $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ with the function $$f\left(x\right)=\max\left(x^2,|x|\right)$$
Show that the function $f$ is convex.

I know that $x^2$ and $|x|$ is convex:

For $x^2$:
$$\frac{d^2}{d^2x}\left(x^2\right)=2>0$$
then $x^2$ is convex.

For $|x|$:
$$|\left(1-\lambda\right)x+\lambda y| \leq |\left(1-\lambda\right)x|+|\lambda y|=|(1-\lambda)||x|+|\lambda||y|=\left(1-\lambda \right) f\left(x\right)+\lambda f\left(y\right)$$
Then $|x|$ is convex.

since $x^2$ and $|x|$ both are convex then $\max\left(x^2,|x|\right)$ is convex. Can I conclude that or is it wrong to do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are aware that the max of two convex functions is convex, then you're done. However, it might be worth providing a proof of that fact depending on your level. At the very least, you have the exact correct idea ^_^

Comment: I want to prove it, can do this by using the following $f\left(\left(1-\lambda\right)x+\lambda y\right) \leq \left(1-\lambda\right) f\left(x\right)+\lambda f\left(y\right)$, or do I have to do something else.